# Error linking uWSGI for python2.7 on mac monterey

Tags: python, macos, uwsgi

Trying to pip install uwsgi on my mac for a python2.7 project and running into an issue, looks like a linking issue.
FYI I do it on a virtualenv and the installation works fine on python3 (but I need it on 2.7)
macOS version: Monterey v12.1
pip version: 20.3.4

Here's the output I get:

```
  Collecting uwsgi
  Downloading uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
     |################################| 804 kB 992 kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/<project-name>/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/tmp/pip-wheel-QezAwe
       cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/
  Complete output (157 lines):
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-12.1-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
  Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
  detected CPU cores: 8
  configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -I/usr/local/Cellar/jansson/2.14/include -DUWSGI_JSON -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
  *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
  [thread 0][gcc] core/utils.o
  .
  .
  .
  [thread 6][gcc] plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o
  *** uWSGI linking ***
  gcc -o build/bdist.macosx-12.1-x86_64/wheel/uWSGI-2.0.20.data/scripts/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/json.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -L/usr/local/Cellar/jansson/2.14/lib -ljansson -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a
  ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.tbd for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  *** error linking uWSGI ***
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
    Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/<project-name>/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-MYAX8G/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/d<username>/PycharmProjects/<project-name>/venv/include/site/python2.7/uwsgi
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/
    Complete output (150 lines):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 8
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -I/usr/local/Cellar/jansson/2.14/include -DUWSGI_JSON -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    core/protocol.o is up to date
    .
    .
    .
    plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o is up to date
    *** uWSGI linking ***
    gcc -o /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/data-analysis/venv/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/json.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -L/usr/local/Cellar/jansson/2.14/lib -ljansson -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a
    ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.tbd for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    *** error linking uWSGI ***
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/<project-name>/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-YXzD6_/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-MYAX8G/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/<project-name>/venv/include/site/python2.7/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is facing same issue on Monterey and XCode 13.2, I solved by removing below code from:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python.tbd
```

> ```
> allowable-clients:
>   - targets:         [ x86_64-macos, arm64-macos, arm64e-macos ]
>     clients:         [ Accounts, CPAN, CoreAnalytics_executables, CoreGraphicsBindings, 
>                        CoreMLTools, CoreNLPFramework, CreateMLTest, CreateML_tests, 
>                        DataDetectorsCore_executables, Feldspar, GPUDriversIntel, 
>                        HIDSensingPipeline, HSComposer, LanguageModeling, Mica, MobileBluetooth_DevTools, 
>                        MobileQuickLook_iosmac, PencilKit_swiftoverlay_iosmac, Photos_Swift, 
>                        Picholine, Raft, RaftFramework, RaftFrameworkExternal, SpeechRecognitionCore_executables, 
>                        Stocks, TimeSync_exec, UIKit_swiftoverlay, accounts_tool, 
>                        appletrace_bindings-python2, ausiss, caffeconverter, cgdump, 
>                        coremlpython, disasm, duallinkanalyse, eoslib, fastsim, gxtools, 
>                        lldbPluginScriptInterpreterPython2, lldb_host, mrecfpu, pdsasm, 
>                        pmrec, pmrec.tmp, py_dasm, pydis, pydis-s2a8, pyobjc, python.exe, 
>                        python_modules, pythonw, pytrace, quarantine_test, rogueasm, 
>                        sim, sim_bindings-python2, testbotctl, testbotd, testbotd-base, 
>                        testbottask, timesyncanalyse, timesynclogextract ]
> ```